# Yandex Maps JS API v3 - YMapClusterer и двигающиеся точки

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Задача: отобразить на карте с использованием кластеризатора большое количество точек, часть из которых активно двигается.

Из API кластеризатора складывается впечатление, что он в целом не предназначен для такого случая. Быстрые эксперименты показывают, что попытка вызывать `update({ features })` с обновлёнными координатами не оказывает видимого эффекта, а захват создаваемых маркеров во внешней коллекции, и их последующее ручное перемещение, вызывают в кластеризаторе нежелательные эффекты (в частности, периодическое исчезновение/появление маркеров без видимой причины).

По этому поводу два запроса на совет:

1. есть ли ощущение, что я упустил что-то важное?
2. если захочется сделать собственную реализацию кластеризатора, не обладающую указанными недостатками, будут ли советы к подходу к реализации? Возможно, какие-то источники вдохновения?

Мои предположения по поводу 2:

- использовать существующий метод `clusterByGrid` из пакета `clusterer` для основного "мяса" логики
- вызывать его по определённому таймеру, примерно определив частоту обновлений от количества известных точек в области видимости / зума
- реализовать заново логику жизненного цикла сущностей маркеров/кластеров, учитывая их перемещения
- инкапсулировать всё это в подкласс `YMapComplexEntity` с необходимыми кастомными методами.

Comment: Реализовал кастомный кластеризатор согласно предположениям, работает, требованиям удовлетворяет. Получается и динамически регулировать частоту обновления (включая симуляцию "плавного движения" при зуме), избегая пересчётов кластеризатора, когда это не требуется.